# gulp-sass sourcemaps not working in chrome dev console

Tags: sass, gulp, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, gulp-sass

I'm having a hard times trying to use `sass` source maps to edit `sass` source in `chrome developer console`. To compile sass i'm using `gulp-sass` 2.0.4 and `gulp-sourcemaps` 1.5.2.
Here's a code snippet:

```
function fsass() {
  gulp.src('./public/styles/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())    
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))    
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/css'));
}
```

In chrome dev console i have mapped my .css file to a network resource, .map is stored alongside with .css, yet all I can see is only this .css file showing on element inspecting. Also Usage of source files is checked in chrome settings.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you're sure there's nothing wrong with your source map, try opening the page in an incognito window. If it works there, then it's probably a caching issue. Clear your cache and quit Chrome. Reopen it to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: If clearing the cache doesn't work, try running your site on a different port number.

Comment: @Max having same issue, do you find out anything to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mosijava was an ancient issue, not having it rn, dev tool sometime (rarely) can bug out though, for me - reloading chrome or removing/adding source folder mapping usually helps.